# How to enable http logging for provisioning API java client?

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I am using java classes AppsForYourDomainService UserService 
from package com.google.gdata.client and could not figure out how to configure http client log.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent article detailing how to do this at:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/debugging_client_libs#java

Comment: Thanks I have seen this one,kind of disappointment, cannot print request response body.